# Filtering a polygon by area with multiple iterations?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, iterator, habitat-modeling

I am currently working on a habitat conservation map in ArcGIS 10.3.  I want to filter out smaller areas from my polygon layer, but as I'm not sure what the appropriate habitat patch size is for this, I plan to perform multiple filtering operations.

For example, I'd like to filter out patches that are less than 5 acres in area and yield a layer output; then I'd like to repeat this filtering process with layer outputs for 10 acres, 20, 50, and 100.  I can do this manually, but it seems tedious enough that I could set this up in ModelBuilder or Python-but I need help with setting this up, as I am unsure of how multiple iterators will work in ModelBuilder with ArcGIS 10.3.